# What is the benefit(s) of self hosted web API?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, self-hosting

Actually! I'm putting this question Just to know that what is the exact ways to host if i have a solution and there is a API project any many others?
And exactly why we need self hosting?

Please Guide me 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use self-hosting of web-api in windows console and windows service type of programs (daemons). Such type of applications are long-running processes that doesn't have any UI and can run without installing IIS role.

The benefit is that web-api controllers can have direct access to your application's data.

Possible use cases for self-hosting when you have such app are:

- ping that application is running (you can have separate monitoring service that will poll your applications with web-api ping request and warns you with emails)
- request of current application's status (debug/diagnostics purpose)
- provide REST API to external services
- provide some UI - you can return static pages implemented as SPA (Single Page Application) and use REST requests to consume data for UI.

Also I have used web-api in specific scenarios of MS-SQL DB <---> Application interaction:

- starting with Sql Server 2012 you cannot use WCF in .NET stored procedures (you get error on installing stored procedure that uses WCF).
- in Sql Server 2005 and 2008 you can use WCF, but errors will occurs when you update .NET Framework on server (assembly version in SQL Server differs from assembly version in GAC error).
- web-api is the resque here because you can use [System.Net.WebClient class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx) in your stored procedures with SQL Server 2005 and later without any restrictions.

Comment: One More thing suppose i have 2 projects in one solution 
1st => Web API Project
2nd=> My Project
then How to Host As Self-Hosting
and Is this approach is good and if not then what should i do?

Comment: You can host as self-hosting in your project just referencing your web-api project and starting the host.

There is two self-host options: 

- with [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/) is recommended way
- with [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost/) is outdated an not recommended way