# When to self host ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

While reading a blog I found that ASP.NET Web API could be self hosted. There are loads of links telling how to self host Web API but I could not find any link explaining when it makes sense over IIS. Could someone please point me to couple of scenarios where self hosting of Web API is more suited than IIS hosting.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: May be this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226331/what-is-the-benefits-of-self-hosted-web-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you would use self hosted Web API to get a **better performance** and to **get rid of unnecessary pipelines of IIS**. Additionally, you get better control over handling http requests, configuration and so forth. Since you have less dependencies on other apps your deployment and troubleshooting gets easier and less complicated.

Having said that, you have to write code to handle everything, even simple things (such as returning static files) that are simply done by IIS.

Thanks to the ASP.net Core, you'd be able to host your apps on Linux, MacOS and Windows. So, going **cross platform** would be another reason for using self hosted apps.

Comment: Should I Create Self Hosted Web API or Use Asp.Net Core Web API ? can you answer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840411/create-self-hosted-web-api-or-use-asp-net-core-web-api) ?